# Strange router work with centos 6

Tags: centos, networking

I've TP-LINK TL-WR720N
192.168.0.1
and 2 client
windows 192.168.0.100 (wireless)
centos 192.168.0.101 (wire)

**from tp-link**

```
ping 192.168.0.1 - OK
ping 192.168.0.100 - OK
ping 192.168.0.101 - time out
ping google.com - OK
```

**from windows**

```
ping 192.168.0.1 - OK
ping 192.168.0.100 - OK
ping 192.168.0.101 - OK
ping google.com - OK
```

**from centos**

```
ping 192.168.0.1 - time out
ping 192.168.0.100 - OK
ping 192.168.0.101 - OK
ping google.com - time out

[andrew@simple ~]$ cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
DEVICE=eth0
HWADDR=00:16:17:1E:3A:90
TYPE=Ethernet
UUID=b37aec51-85ba-47c8-bdcd-a1b6f47a2b98
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
BOOTPROTO=dhcp

[andrew@simple ~]$ netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0

[andrew@simple ~]$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
192.168.0.101 simple.andwiz.ru simple

[andrew@simple ~]$ uname -a
Linux simple.andviz.ru 2.6.32-696.el6.i686 #1 SMP Tue Mar 21 18:53:30 UTC 2017 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

All firewall, rules, filters - off. I can connect ssh from win to centos.

**How it possible?**

Comment: Do you use the latest firmware for your router?

Comment: Have a look at your router menu (Advanced Settings -> Security -> Advanced Security). There are 2 checkboxes: <Ignore Ping Packet From WAN Port> and <Forbid Ping Packet From LAN Port>. Maybe it's blocked there.

Comment: Nope, DoS Protection -  disabled. And I can ping win->centos, win -> tp-link

Comment: version of firmware - 4.19.0 Build 150711 Rel.57147n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the same network 192.168.0/24 both for the wireless and wired network.

Either you defined them as bridged, or you have to defined two different networks, with for instance the wireless interface of your linksys having the address 192.168.2.1/255.255.255.0.

Comment: I can't set two subnet http://www.tp-link.in/resources/simulator/TL-WR720N_V2/index.htm . TP-LINK using one for both wireless and wire.

Comment: DHCP in router using 192.168.0.100..199. I add manual IP(disable dhcp in centos) for centos 192.168.0.10 and it work. Thanks.